# (beginner) First Django Web App - models.py

Tags: python, django, dynamic, html

I'm starting my first Django web app [after completing the Django official tutorial and Django Girls tutorial].. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around setting up models. I have something now that works, but I feel that it is quite inefficient and I rather learn the correct way before going forward..

Starting out - When learning a new programming language, a lot of people (on the internet) advise to pick a topic/hobby you enjoy and make a project out of it. I enjoy sports a lot and wanted to recreate a virtual scoreboard, similar to ESPN or any other sports web site.

My models.py currently looks like this -

```
class Game(models.Model):
    # start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    today = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game_outcome = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    game_quarter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    game_clock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    away_team_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    away_team_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    away_team_city = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    away_team_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    away_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    home_team_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    home_team_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    home_team_city = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    home_team_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    home_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

but I feel like this is way too many variables and not the correct way to go about it. I have also tried something like this...

```
class Day(models.Model):
    today = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class Game(models.Model):
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    game_outcome = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    game_quarter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    game_clock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    away_team_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    away_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    home_team_id = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    home_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    team_id = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    team_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    team_city = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Every Day has 0 to xx amount of games. Than every game has: outcome (null or 'FINAL'), current quarter ('1' or null), current clock ('00:00' or null), away team ('CHA'), away score ('99'), home team('TOR') and home score('102'). Then I would take the team id's and compare that to the class Team. Every Team has a class (for css: 'tor'), a city ('Toronto'), and full name ('Raptors').

Still it's not sticking in my head. I can get the all the information in a python shell and output to my html/css, but I feel it's inefficient. Also, every Day has it's own html page (similar to website.com/nba/scores/20150112/) and is filled with all the games from that day.

Sorry if this is too beginner to ask; I have spent a lot of time looking for answers and finally decided to post on stackoverlow (my first question ever).

Any information or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general idea of your model approach is good enough. Nevertheless, I'd encourage you to go through [Django's ORM relationships documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#relationships). It's ok if you want to use strings as your primary key, but let Django's ORM know that by using [the proper model field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#primary-key). If you use primary and foreign keys (relationships), your dbms will create indexes over the necessary fields, resulting in more efficient queries. Let me know if this help! Good luck with your project!

**UPDATE:**

It would be something like this:

```
class Day(models.Model):
    today = models.DateField(default=date.today)

class Game(models.Model):
    game_outcome    = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    game_quarter    = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    game_clock      = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    day = models.ForeignKey(Day, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    away_team       = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='away_team')
    away_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    home_team       = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='home_team')
    home_team_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    team_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    team_city = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
```

Notice that I omitted all `id` fields, since django will use one automatically created, which behaves the same as `AutoField`. Also notice that since `Game` has two references to the same class (`Team`), it is necessary to provide the extra parameter `related_name`. Mor info about it in [django docs about `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name).

This way, you can do things like

```
game = Game.objects.find(1)
away_team_name = game.away_team.team_name
```

You can access the associated `Team` class in the `away_team` variable. No need to call `away_team_id` at all.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!

So if I understand correctly after reading the docs, this would be the set-up...?

class Day

class Game... has a many-to-one relationship with Day (10 games, only 1 day)

class Team... has a one-to-one relationship with Game (each home_team_id and away_team_id are direct one-to-one relationships with their team_name, team_city, and team_class in class Team itself)

Comment: @asapzacy: well conceptually, in `Game` class, foreign keys to `Team` are also many-to-one realtionships, since one `Team` can participate in many `Game`s. Check the update

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand the more ForeignKeys you use the more load you put on the database. But it also depends a lot on the views.py code as well. Second of all you don't need to use `team_id` as a field name if you use a ForeignKey. Just mention the class name and it will automatically create an `_id` for the field.

Look at the following code:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    today = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    game_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # You don't need this line, an id field is created for EVERY model class even if you don't specify it.
    game_outcome = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    game_quarter = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    game_clock = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('Team')

class Team(models.Model):
    team_class = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

You can see that I have created another class by the name of `Team` and put four fields on that which was repeated in your original `Game` class. Then I have connected the `Team` class to the `Game` class with `ForeignKey`. If you install SQLiteBrowser and check out the database file then you will see that the `away_team` field is actually the `away_team_id` field in the database because Django takes care of that. You don't need to create `id` fields, just use relations like `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`, etc. Off the top of my head this is the only thing that I can suggest.

Judging by the scope of this project you will not put too much pressure on the database with too many relations, so don't worry about that now. That' it. If you have any question more specific you can ask. Cheers! :)

P.S. I am not sure about your project details so use whichever relation you see fit, be it one-to-one, many-to-one or many-to-many, etc. Read the docs for more details. :)